# How to keep a list of all active users of the web app?

Tags: django

I am new to Django. I have been trying a store a list of all active ip addresses which are using the web app currently.

My approach is to add a new entry to the database table with the IP address of the user as soon as a person logs in. And keep updating the timestamp column (`LastPingTime`) in the table with the current time every 3 seconds or so. So the active ip addresses would be all the rows in the table whose `LastPingTime` is less than or equal to 3 seconds from the current time. But I don't know to go about it. Please help with this. How do I run a periodic function which does this for every new user?​
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can query for these users with:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now
from datetime import timedelta

MyModel.objects.filter(LastPingTime__gte=now()-timedelta(seconds=3))
```

This will return a `QuerySet` of `MyModel`s that have a `LastPingTime` that is later than or equal to three seconds ago.

> **Note**: field names are usually written as `last_ping_time`, not <s>`LastPingTime`</s>.

Comment: Thank you so much. Will keep the tip in mind. 
I wanted to know how to run the periodic function which will update the database every 3 seconds for every user.